# How to get the "Really Hard? This be Impossible!" achievement?

Tags: lego-movie

> **Really hard? This be Impossible!** Destroyed 50 Enemies as Metal Beard

Can this be done with the Metalbeard minifigure or does it have to be the full-size Metalbeard? I have played as nothing but Metalbeard through a dozen level replays as I clean up Golden Manuals but this achievement has not popped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://www.trueachievements.com/a184153/really-hard-this-be-impossible-achievement.htm) says that you do it in level 10 of Story Mode.

> During Story Mode Level 10, Infiltrate the Octan Tower, you will eventually be given control of Metalbeard.
>
> While there is a set number of robot you have to destroy before you can move forward, you can remain in the area and enemies will respawn infinitely from one of the doors. Be sure not to progress forward by using Metalbeard to toss an enemy because after that the enemies will stop spawning from the doorway.
>
> Just keep bashing them until the achievement pops.